# remove operation deletes the whole list

Tags: c++, list

I don't understand why this instruction deletes all the elements in the list

```
z->data().remove(d);
```

z and d are these:
Z
[image]
D
[image]

```
std::list<Data>& data()const{return this->d;};
```

This is equality comparison

```
template <class Key, class Data>
bool operator== (const Node<Key,Data>& lhs, const Node<Key,Data>& rhs)
{ return lhs.key()==rhs.key() && lhs.data()==rhs.data(); }
```

Comment: How is equality comparison implemented for `Node` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the argument of `remove` (`d` in your case) compares equal to each element of the list, the entire list will get "removed". This is apparently what happens in your case.

Your list seems to contain objects of class type `Node<char, unsigned long>`. Did you write the equality comparison operator `==` for these `Node` objects properly?